# Big O Notation data structures

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have a doubt related to Big O Notation
for the equation

```
f(n)=3n+8
```

how do we find the upper bound and how do we find big O notation
The solution given is

`3n+8<=4n` and `n>8`, where `c=4` and `n_0=8`

I am not sure how this solution was found. Can you please explain how this solution was reached?

Answer (score 3):

Mathematical definition of Big-Oh notation from [CLRS](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms):

```
O(g(n)) = { f(n) : there exists positive constants c and n_0 such that 0 <= f(n) <= c.g(n) for all n >= n_0 }
```

Let `f(n)=3n+8`.

Then, we have to find positive constants `c` and `n_0` such that `0 <= 3n+8 <= c.g(n) for all n >= n_0`.

Let `g(n)=n`. (you can try it out for various functions if you want)

Then, `0 <= 3n+8 <= cn for all n >= n_0`.

This expression will hold true only when the value of `c` is greater than `3` **and** value of `n` is greater than or equal to `8`. If this is not the case, then this linear inequality will fail. For instance:

- if `c = 3`, then we will get `0 <= 3n+8 <= 3n` which is false.
- if `c = 4` and `n_0 = 7`, then we will get `0 <= 3n+8 <= 4n` which implies `0 <= 3.7+8 <= 4.7` which gives `0 <= 29 <= 28` which again, is false.

So, we can conclude that `f(n) = O(n) for c = 4 and n_0 = 8`.

[This](http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf) is a great resource if you wish to learn more.

Comment: Also note that any value above `3` will also do. For example, using `{c=3.5, n=16}`, `{c=3.1, n=80}`, `{c=3.001, n=8000}` etc.